# c# running daemon command line

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have several batch files that I need to execute using C#, the problem is at the end of the first batch file it is running a daemon process. This is causing the second batch file to never be executed because of the WaitForExit(). I can not take this out because I dont know how much time the first batch file need to run (until it hits running the daemon)

```
BatchFile1.bat ->
BatchFile2.bat ->
BatchFile3.bat ->
BatchFile4.bat
```

inside BatchFile1.bat, I have blah, blah, blah and at the end it is running a daemon process which of course will never exit

```
//not exit , even if there is error
public void Run_Process(string process_name, string s)     
{                
    Process myProcess = new Process();

    myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
    myProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C " + process_name + s;

    myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    myProcess.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    myProcess.Start();
    string standard_output = myProcess.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
    myProcess.WaitForExit();
    Console.WriteLine(standard_output);
}
```

Comment: Can you just change your bat file to start the daemon in the background?

Comment: I can not change the bat file. Forbidden

Comment: Can you post the .bat code?

Comment: I can't. But nothing special really. I should concentrate on "how to execute this". modifying the batch file is out of the picture.

Comment: How is the daemon process kicked off?  With `START`, or does it active e.g. a Windows Service?

Comment: Does the .bat write anything to stdout that you could wait for?

Comment: I guess you could poll for the existence of the daemon process..

Comment: Why not starting your Process in a task ?  System.Threading.Task.Factory.StartNew( ......

Comment: If you're using `start`, I would expect the bat file not to wait for the daemon process..

Answer (score 0):

To Execute a cmd.exe this might work:

```
static void ExecuteCommand(string command)
{
int exitCode;
ProcessStartInfo processInfo;
Process process;

processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", "/c " + command);
processInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// *** Redirect the output ***
processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

process = Process.Start(processInfo);
process.WaitForExit();

// *** Read the streams ***
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

exitCode = process.ExitCode;

Console.WriteLine("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
Console.WriteLine("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
Console.WriteLine("ExitCode: " + exitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
process.Close();
}

static void Main()
{
ExecuteCommand("echo testing");
}
```